# C# Insert IList<string> into table using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#

I have IList which I am trying to insert into a `SQL table` and running into performance issue. I am now trying to insert the content of `IList<string>` to a SQL table using `SqlBulkCopy`.

```
public string toTbl(IList < string > records) {
    const string connectionString = @ "Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=user;Password=password;";    
    try {
        var studentData = from record in records
        let srec = record.Split('|')
        select new Student {
            ID = srec[0],
            Student = srec[1],
            Grade = srec[2]
        };

        foreach(var i in studentData) {
            using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                sqlConnection.Open();    
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Student] ([ID], [Student], [Grade]) VALUES (@ID, @Student, @Grade)", sqlConnection)) {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", i.ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", i.Student);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", i.Grade);    
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        message = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question though?

Comment: Hi @Brien, I am trying write this method using SqlBulkCopy class into a table that has Identity column and running into error.

Comment: So what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

You shall not insert the List using SqlBulkCopy.
Refer this [link for SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to construct the data either to a datatable or datarow or a reader to write it to the database using SqlBulkCopy.

Also you should not add values to an identity column, from your comments I assume [ID] is your identity column. The below example has a datatable (dtStudent) with 2 columns Student and Grade, it will writes all the records into the database

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
{
  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Student", "Student");
  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Grade", "Grade"); 
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Student";
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtStudent);
}
```

You can also insert using DataRow[], refer the above mentioned link